# Prevent apache from changing content type when rewriting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, gzip, content-type

I have a static web page and want to improve the loading performance by providing gzip-versions of all available files. The page is running on an apache server *mod_gzip* and I can't change any configuration except the .htaccess file.
Thus I create gzip files during the build process and want to rewrite the incoming requests to the .gz files.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    ReWriteCond %{HTTP:accept-encoding} gzip
    ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.+\.gz$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f
    RewriteRule (.+) $1.gz [L]
</IfModule>
```

The rewriting works perfectly, but unfotunately the server also changes the *Content-Type* of the response to *application/x-gzip* which makes the browser downloading the file and not rendering it. Is there a way to prevent the apache server from changing the content type and to render the page instead of downloading the gz?

Comment: Which files do you have a gz version for? html, css, js?

Comment: Yes, html, css and js. But also font files (eot, ttf, woff...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires you to have 2 versions of the file in the following format. For instance:

```
index.html
index.html.gz

styles.css
styles.css.gz

scripts.js
scripts.js.gz
```

This htaccess will rewrite the request to send the gz version to the browser but also maintain the type of the original file. You have to force the type of the file you want to send. Otherwise it will use the `application/x-gzip` and the browser will download the file.

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/font-ttf application/font-woff application/font-otf image/svg+xml
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f
    RewriteRule (.*\.(html|css|js|eot|ttf|woff|otf|svg))$ $1.gz [L]
</IfModule>

AddEncoding x-gzip .gz

<FilesMatch .*\.html.gz>
    ForceType text/html
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch .*\.css.gz>
    ForceType text/css
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch .*\.js.gz>
    ForceType application/javascript
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch .*\.eot.gz>
    ForceType application/vnd.ms-fontobject
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch .*\.ttf.gz>
    ForceType application/font-ttf
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch .*\.woff.gz>
    ForceType application/font-woff
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch .*\.otf.gz>
    ForceType application/font-otf
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch .*\.svg.gz>
    ForceType image/svg+xml
</FilesMatch>
```